# Why when I change value of char array in C it messes up?

Tags: c, string

I ran into this problem where when I get value of one array and put it in another it messes up.

```
char X[255] = " ", Y[134] = " ";
scanf("%s", X);
Y[j] = X[i];
```

and I get output like: `X[i]` is in fact `1`, but `Y[j]` came up like `49`, for `2` it is `50` and it continues like this to number `10` where it is again `49`

Do you know how can I prevent this?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. Sounds like you are talking about [ASCII codes](https://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: What are the values of `i` and `j`?

Comment: `49` is the ASCII code for the character `1`. Are you printing an array element as a number instead of character?

Comment: Why even bother initializing with an empty space?

Comment: @Haris — can you explain why you think `char X[255] = " ";` (or with a comma and another variable definition after it instead of the semicolon) is invalid in C18?  What changed between C11 and C18 to make it invalid?

Comment: @Haris `" "` is not the empty initializer; `{ }` is. (No comment on the validity of `char X[255] = " ";` in any version of C.)

Comment: @Haris, `" "` is an equivalent to `{' ', 0}`. Both are perfectly valid initializers for character arrays.

Comment: @ikegami I misjudged, which is undefined behavior on my part. I take my comment back.

Answer (score 1):

- 49 is the ASCII encoding of `1`. The string `1` therefore consists of characters 49 and 0.
- 50 is the ASCII encoding of `2`. The string `2` therefore consists of characters 50 and 0.
- 48 is the ASCII encoding of `0`. The string `10` consists of characters 49, 48 and 0.

You did not specify what you want. Maybe you want to read in a decimal number?

```
int i;
scanf( "%d", &i );
```

Comment: I want make some kind of calculator where you input example like 2/1*8 and it automatically get operations and return result to you in this example it vould be 8. It si my first project with c lang so I'm bit confused I have some konolige of javaScript and bit of java, but I neer worked with c.

Comment: You'd see the same thing in Java. If you read in a line as a string and you printed the value of the chars, they'd be the same. You'd have `'1'`, `'2'`, etc, not the value `1`, `2`, etc. So either read a number as shown, or convert the string to a number (e.g. using `atoi`).